# Как по одному клику открыть сразу 2 календаря?

Tags: angularjs, javascript

Проект построен на Angular-js.
Нужно по нажатии на одну иконку открыть сразу два календаря на текущий месяц, для выбора интервала дат.
Результат записать в скрытый input.
Как выбрать дату, не закрывая календарь, я уже понял, но не получается отрисовать дополнительный календарь справа от имеющегося.

Тестировал вот на этом примере: [link text](http://plnkr.co/edit/WabrlbvbEIEoDMoovo6h?p=preview).

Для того чтобы не закрывался, добавил атрибут со значением - `close-on-date-selection="false"`.

**Обновление**

Методом научного тыка, нашел вот такое решение:

```
<div class="form-horizontal"> <input type="text" ng-model="dt1" is-open="opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-on-date-selection="false" /> <input type="text" ng-model="dt2" is-open="opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-on-date-selection="false" /> <button class="btn" ng-click="open()"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button> </div>
```

Вот только как всплывающие календари объединить в одном блоке?

Поставить рядом можно при помощи CSS - убрать `position: absolute;` в UL.

Попутный вопрос - как открыть календари в определенном блоке?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так вот: http://plnkr.co/edit/3ObIyKLqHGqKHTiV7exn?p=preview

Дальше дело за CSS.

Всем спасибо.